# OAuthException error asking for details of a payment

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, restfb

I am using the new version of the payments: [Local currency Payments](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/payments/) and my tests are given me different results. Sometimes everything is well, but sometimes an error appeared when I am asking to the facebook graph for more details about the payment.

The url that I am using is:

https://graph.facebook.com/PAYMENT_ID?access_token=APP_ACCESS_TOKEN

PAYMENT_ID, is the id of a payment (status=completed) and the APP_ACCESS_TOKEN, is the application access token. Both are good values.

The error that appear sometimes is:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 2
   }
}
```

I was using [restfb](http://restfb.com/) and I have tried the same thing by hand, but nothing seems to change.

Has anyone had the same problem?